# JMESPATH for counting number the of values beginning with specific string

Tags: json, jmespath

Provided the JSON below, how would I construct a JAMESPATH script to return the number of times the value in the "Code" key begins with "BS"

In this example my expected return would be: "2"

Thanks in advance!

```js
{
    "Data": {
        "Matches": {
          "ReasonCodes": [
            {
              "Reason": {
                "Code": "BS02931298"
              }
            },
            {
                "Reason": {
                  "Code": "BS02931298:"
                }
            },
            {
                "Reason": {
                  "Code": "AS02931298"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just kept digging and I finally came up with the answer:

```
 length(Data.Matches.ReasonCodes[?Reason.starts_with(Code, 'BS')])
```

Comment: Nice answer! json and jmespath can sometimes be terrible to work with...

Comment: Thank you! I've only been working with JSON for 5 months, and JMESpath today, and I totally agree. haha